# Como passar um "title" em um "UIAlertController" do tipo Int com swift?

Tags: swift, int, alert

Boa tarde, pessoal.

Estou chamando um alert no meu código em que preciso que o "title" dele seja o id de retorno de um JSON, meu objeto json tem id e status, o id é do tipo Int e o status é do tipo String, tentei converter o id para string, mas na hora de carregar na tela ele fica diferente do retorno do json, segue abaixo a parte do meu código que está carregando o id e imagens do simulador ao executar o código:

```
func showActionSheetSenha(){
    var actions = [UIAlertAction]()

    for obj in containerSenha.arraySenhas{
        let status = obj.status
        let id = String(format: "%f", obj.id)

        actions.append(Alerta.createAction(id, style: .Default, handler: {(paramAction) in
            self.campoField.text = id
            self.senhaAtual = obj as Senha
        }))
    }

    Alerta.showAlert(nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet, actions: actions, viewController: self) { () -> Void in
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Quando eu substituo o id pelo status para aparecer no alert, ele funciona, mostra o status normal. Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já tentou em vez de:

```
let id = String(format: "%f", obj.id)
```

fazer:

```
let id = "\(obj.id)"
```

???

Comment: Deu certo, eu não tinha tentado isso, mas funcionou, muito obrigada :)